Why are "half of a loaf" and "half of an orange" not correct, whereas "half of a pizza" is correct?
my conclusion from forum.thefreedictionary.com:

half of a loaf — incorrect
half a loaf — correct
half of an orange — incorrect
half an orange — correct

my conclusion from english.stackexchange.com:

half of a pizza — correct
half a pizza — correct

Why are "half of a loaf" and "half of an orange" not correct, whereas "half of a pizza" is correct?

I don't think "half of a loaf" is wrong, nor is "half on an orange"  Both are correct grammatically, and it's not hard to find examples  "My miniature schnauzer just ate half of a loaf of bread".

The Free Dictionary is a forum where anyone can write anything. All those 'incorrects' you found are in fact correct. The 'of' in a half of, a quarter of, etc, is optional and may be used or omitted. Use a proper dictionary

They didn't even technically say "half of a loaf" was wrong, just that it doesn't refer to a quantity (it refers to an object). Usually it doesn't matter but it might occasionally.

First, it’s probably worth pointing out that describing a usage as either correct or wrong is fairly treacherous because there is no absolute standard. Language (every language) is a squishy, blurry-boundaried, constantly evolving phenomenon. There are standards of acceptability and appropriateness, but they cannot fail to be at least somewhat arbitrary.
Then, in contrast to the kind of prescriptive approach suggested by labels like correct and wrong, there is the descriptive one, which is the essentially universal practice among linguists.  It’s not about what should or shouldn’t be done, but what about what actually is done.
And from that perspective, I’d offer the results of Google n-grams. If one queries the relative frequencies of half an orange and half of an orange within their vast text corpus, it does report that the version with of is far less frequently encountered. But then again, the analogous query substituting a pizza for an orange responds, “Ngrams not found: Half of a pizza.”
On balance, there is no basis to conclude that the premise of your question—that the acceptability of expressions with half of a depends on the complement one appends to it—holds for English. One can only wonder what might lead anyone, including those opining at TheFreeDictionary, to suggest that it does.

Paul, it all depends on register and context. There are things that are absolutely wrong. Even a dialectal usage (We is rich, for example), can contain dialectal mistakes, like by Hollywood writers who don't know the dialect. Did you see Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri? The British scripwriter wrote a brilliant scrip but he made a dialect mistake. He used shit as an adjective like Brits instead of using shitty, the AmE usage. It jumped out at me.

Your ngram is case-sensitive. see https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half+of+a+pizza%2Chalf+a+pizza&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true

I'm not sure why you think the usages you listed are incorrect.
These are all correct:

There is half of a loaf of rye bread left.
There is still half a loaf in the breadbox.


I ate one half of an orange. He ate the other half.
I ate half an orange.


One half of the pizza has pepperoni.
I can't believe I ate half a pizza!

